# Changing HTML Form Alignment

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to increase the space between the label and the input box for my form. I will post the image and current code below. Just wondering what line of code I'd need to add to increase the space. Thanks!

Also, is there any way centre evereything so I can move the iFrame to the centre of my page and it will automatically display equally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wra6I.png)

```
<style>
body {background-color: transparent;}
body {font-family: avenir;}
</style>

<META HTTPS-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<form action="https://example.example.com/servlet/servlet.Example?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">


<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D5E0000000UJe">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://example.com/">


<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br>

Date of Birth:<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"><input  id="00N5E000000rknN" name="00N5E000000rknN" size="12" type="text" /></span><br><br>

<label for="city">City</label><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

<label for="mobile">Mobile</label><input  id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br>

Current/Previous School/University:<input  id="00N5E000000rwVf" maxlength="100" name="00N5E000000rwVf" size="20" type="text" /><br><br>

Course you would like to study:<input  id="00N5E000000rkdr" maxlength="255" name="00N5E000000rkdr" size="20" type="text"/><br><br>

<label for="lead_source">Where did you hear about us?</label><select  id="lead_source" name="lead_source"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Ahmed Al-Ajmi">Ahmed Al-Ajmi</option>
<option value="British Council">British Council</option>
<option value="Career day">Career day</option>
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="Flier / Poster">Flier / Poster</option>
<option value="Google">Google</option>
<option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
<option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
<option value="University Website_(Please specify)">University Website_(Please specify)</option>
<option value="Web">Web</option>
</select><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be helpful for you to use an actual label for each item. Perhaps that's your intention.

If you were to use labels for each item, you could simply add this style (I used 12px for the example, but of course you could use whatever works best for you):

```
label { margin-right: 12px; }
```

I'm not sure what you're looking for regarding the iFrame, as it was not included in the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but if you'd like a space in between the label and the input form, simply put a space inbetween them..

So

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>
```

would become

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label> <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>
```

Alternatively, you could just assign a class to the labels and add padding/margin to them.